# How can I write a ':hover' condition for 'a:before' and 'a:after'?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

How can I write `:hover` and `:visited` condition for `a:before`?

I'm trying `a:before:hover`, but it's not working.

Answer (score 579, accepted):

This depends on what you're actually trying to do.

If you simply wish to apply styles to a `:before` pseudo-element when the `a` element matches a pseudo-class, you need to write `a:hover:before` or `a:visited:before` instead. Notice the pseudo-element comes *after* the pseudo-class (and in fact, at the very end of the entire selector). Notice also that they are two different things; calling them both "pseudo-selectors" is going to confuse you once you run into syntax problems such as this one.

If you're writing CSS3, you can denote a pseudo-element with double colons to make this distinction clearer. Hence, `a:hover::before` and `a:visited::before`. But if you're developing for legacy browsers such as IE8 and older, then you can get away with using single colons just fine.

This specific order of pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements is stated in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selector-syntax):

> One pseudo-element may be appended to the last sequence of simple selectors in a selector.
>
> A *sequence of simple selectors* is a chain of simple selectors that are not separated by a combinator. It always begins with a type selector or a universal selector. No other type selector or universal selector is allowed in the sequence.
>
> A *simple selector* is either a type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

A pseudo-class is a simple selector. A pseudo-element, however, is not, even though it resembles a simple selector.

However, for user-action pseudo-classes such as `:hover`<sup>1</sup>, if you need this effect to apply *only* when the user interacts with the pseudo-element itself but not the `a` element, then this is not possible other than through some obscure layout-dependent workaround. As implied by the text, standard CSS pseudo-elements cannot currently have pseudo-classes. In that case, you will need to apply `:hover` to an actual child element instead of a pseudo-element.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Of course, this does not apply to link pseudo-classes such as `:visited` as in the question, since pseudo-elements aren't links.</sub>

Comment: It should be pointed out that that puts the hover on the parent element - which causes the decoration to be applied even if the ::after pseudoelement is not under the mouse, as long as its parent is.

Comment: It should also be noted that there are a number of things that *don't* respond to this because of the way the layout rules are specified – e.g. `text-decoration`.

Comment: @Chris Krycho: Indeed - I actually happen to have an explanation for this specific issue with regard to pseudo-elements [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474780/hoverbefore-text-decoration-none-has-no-effects/11481121#11481121). Of course, it's worth clarifying that the issue itself has no connection with pseudo-class/pseudo-element *selectors*, but is as you point out, a layout issue.

Comment: Sinlge colon (:) designates pseudo-classes and double colon (::) designates pseudo-elements. So it should be a:hover::before

Comment: @mwb: Of course, assuming IE8 support is not needed. This answer was posted several months before Selectors 3 even became a recommendation, and I'm not inclined to change it given that IE8 is still significantly used.

Answer (score 153):

Write `a:hover::before` instead of `a::before:hover`: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/PJspQ/1/).

Comment: @mikkelbreum do you have a reference to prove that?

Comment: @bungeshea: That is CSS3 syntax. See the comments under my answer (as well as my recent edit). It's a little inaccurate to call it "the" correct syntax though because both single and double colons are permitted for CSS1/2 pseudo-elements. I would call it the *recommended* syntax instead, because the only reason to continue using the legacy syntax today is for supporting IE8 and older.

Comment: @mikkelbreum @sheabunge more info on CSS2 `:after` vs CSS3 `::after` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after (single `:` has better support)

Comment: it is not working for underline :(
http://jsfiddle.net/porzechowski/u5dhthvq/

Please add also display: inline-block;

http://jsfiddle.net/porzechowski/u89fo4oq/

Answer (score 11):

To change a menu link's text on mouseover (different language text on hover), here is the

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nagendra_rao/YSgKL/2/)

HTML:

```
<a align="center" href="#"><span>kannada</span></a>
```

CSS:

```
span {
    font-size: 12px;
}
a {
    color: green;
}
a:hover span {
    display: none;
}
a:hover:before {
    color: red;
    font-size: 24px;
    content: "ಕನ್ನಡ";
}
```

Comment: This is a lovely answer.

In fact, it inspired me to [extend your fiddle slightly](http://jsfiddle.net/YSgKL/784/) by boosting the font-size of the span text to 24px to match the replacement text, added 3 non-breaking spaces before and after the replacement text so that they occupy the same width, and styled `a:hover::before` with `text-decoration: underline`, which causes the underline to pick up the red color of the replacement text.

Comment: The syntax highlighter does not like it (near "`color: red;`"). What is the reason?

Answer (score 8):

Try to use `.card-listing:hover::after`, `hover`, and `after` using `::`. It will work.

Answer (score 7):

Or you can set `pointer-events:none` to your `a` element and `pointer-event:all` to your `a:before` element, and then add hover CSS to a element:

```css
a{
    pointer-events: none;
}
a:before{
    pointer-events: all
}
a:hover:before{
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Is this working to anyone?

Comment: @Jagath: Good question. The syntax highlighting is off, hinting at a problem.

Comment: Why isn't there a semicolon after `pointer-events: all`?

Comment: This doesn't work, clearly.

Answer (score 2):

[BoltClock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777210/how-can-i-write-a-hover-condition-for-abefore-and-aafter/5777334#5777334) is correct. The only thing I want to append is that if you want to only select the pseudo element, put in a span.

For example:

```html
<li><span data-icon='u'></span> List Element </li>
```

instead of:

```html
<li> data-icon='u' List Element</li>
```

This way you can simply say

```css
ul [data-icon]:hover::before {color: #f7f7f7;}
```

which will only highlight the pseudo element, not the entire li element.

Answer (score -1):

You can also restrict your action to just one class using the right pointed bracket (">"), as I have done in this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    span {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    a {
      color: green;
    }
    .test1>a:hover span {
      display: none;
    }
    .test1>a:hover:before {
      color: red;
      content: "Apple";
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="test1">
    <a href="#"><span>Google</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="test2">
    <a href="#"><span>Apple</span></a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note:** The hover:before switch works only on the .test1 class

Comment: The syntax highlighter does not like it (near "`color: red;`"). What is the reason?