# Combine :after with :hover

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I want to combine `:after` with `:hover` in CSS (or any other pseudo selector).  I basically have a list and the item with the `selected` class has an arrow shape applied using `:after`.  I want the same to be true for objects that are being hovered over but cant quite get it to work.  Heres the code

```css
#alertlist {
  list-style: none;
  width: 250px;
}

#alertlist li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  position: relative;
}

#alertlist li.selected,
#alertlist li:hover {
  color: #f0f0f0;
  background-color: #303030;
}

#alertlist li.selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #303030;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<ul id="alertlist">
  <li>Alert 123</li>
  <li class="selected">Alert 123</li>
  <li>Alert 123</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried to add the rule #alertlist li:hover:after ?

Comment: Short answer: `li:hover:after`. First the :hover on the element, followed by the :after.

Answer (score 300, accepted):

Just append `:after` to your `#alertlist li:hover` selector the same way you do with your `#alertlist li.selected` selector:

```
#alertlist li.selected:after, #alertlist li:hover:after
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right:-10px;
    bottom:0;

    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid #303030;
    content: "";
}
```

Comment: @Chris, what you you probably tried previously was `:after:hover`  as opposed to `:hover:after`. This is what I did initially which frustratingly doesn't work

Comment: @WickyNilliams: That's by design (pseudo-elements vs pseudo-classes) - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777210/how-to-write-hover-condition-for-abefore-and-aafter/5777334#5777334

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for text-decoration in Chrome (v43) nor in FF (v38).

Comment: @geoidesic: Text decorations are a different issue altogether. They especially don't play well with absolute positioning. Nothing to do with pseudo-elements or the `:hover` pseudo-class.

Comment: @BoltClock I'm not using absolute positioning but while I can change the color of my :after content using the above selector syntax, I'm not able to change the text-decoration for the hover state of an :after element on a link. Otherwise text-decoration works just fine.

Comment: @geoidesic: You'll want to post a separate question.

Comment: @BoltClock Ok: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503765/combine-after-with-hover-for-text-decoration-of-a-font-icon

Comment: Isn't :hover:after semantically different from :after:hover?

Comment: @aderchox: It is, which is why :after:hover either doesn't work, or works differently, depending on which year you're in or what browser version you're using (I haven't checked if generated pseudos can have pseudo-classes now, but I know that idea was revived not too long ago).

Answer (score 30):

in scss

```
&::after{
content: url(images/RelativeProjectsArr.png);
margin-left:30px;
}

&:hover{
    background-color:$turkiz;
    color:#e5e7ef;

    &::after{
    content: url(images/RelativeProjectsArrHover.png);
    }
}
```

Comment: anybody needing the css equivalent, this works also `.whateverselector:hover::after`

Answer (score 8):

```
 #alertlist li:hover:after,#alertlist li.selected:after
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right:-10px;
    bottom:0;

    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid #303030;
    content: "";
}​
```

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/6evFd/1/)

Comment: li:hover:afte add this at the same class as selected

Answer (score 4):

**cssSelector**:hover::after,

**cssSelector**:hover::before

lets say we have ***a*** tag

```
a:hover::after {
    /*CSS Property*/
}
a:hover::before {
    /*CSS Property*/
}
```