# Combine :after with :hover for text-decoration of a font icon

Tags: css

How can one get the underline to only apply to the a element and not to the content of the :after?

With the CSS below one can control the color of an :after element on :hover. However, the text-decoration cannot be changed.

Here's the jsfiddle to illustrate the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/500/

Here's the CSS:

```
a {
    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: green;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f061";
}

a:hover:after {
    color: orange;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting the pseudo-element to `display: inline-block` [will remove the text decoration](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/JfGVE/502):

```
a:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f061";
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The underline will still apply to the space in between because you have an `&nbsp;`, though — you can prevent this by [offsetting the pseudo-element with a margin instead of putting hard spaces in the HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/JfGVE/504).

Comment: Doesn't work in IE9/10/11 (no surprises there). Is there an IE friendly fix?

Comment: @DGibbs: Yeah, IE doesn't play well with text decorations on inline-block pseudo-elements. I can't think of a fix.

Comment: Bless you, sir. I've been struggling with this one for 2 hours and your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

afelixj has almost the best answer here, but it has a non-clickable space, even if you remove all of the actual space in the markup.  To fix that, just use `padding-right` on the anchor to create the space to put the icon, then position it at `right: 0`: http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/591/.  Inline-block treats the icon as a character, and it will wrap like text.

Answer (score 0):

Add display: inline-block; to a:after

```
a {
    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: green;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:after {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f061";
}

a:hover:after {
    color: orange;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```