# :hover effect on p:after in specific div

Tags: html, css, selector

I cant seem to properly activate the :hover state for **p** elements inside a parent div

For all **p** elements in the parent div there is an **:after** with 0 width to create an underlining when hovered. I want the width to go from "0" to "2em" when the **p** is hovered.

I'm not sure how to properly target the **p** and the **:after** when hovered.

I though it should look something like below.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <p>Menu Option A</p>
    <p>Menu Option B</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.top_menu_wrapper p:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0em;
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.parent p:hover p:after {
  width: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine :after with :hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233991/combine-after-with-hover)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly - it's the same p you hover you want to manipulate.

So. It's the `.parent p:hover p:after` it's wrong with.

`:hover` and `:after` should be appended onto each other

like this:

```
 .parent p:hover:after {
   width: 2em;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your structure correctly, you're trying to target the `:hover` of the `:after` of any `<p>` tag within the `parent` class.

To do this, you simply need to combine the two pseudo-selectors as one:
`.parent p:hover:after`.

The will target **any** `<p>` child of `.parent`. If you want to target any `<p>` tag that is a **direct** child of the `.parent` class, you can use the greater than symbol (`>`) as `.parent > p:hover:after`.

I've added some `content` to the target selector to help illustrate this.

```css
.parent > p:hover:after {
  width: 2em;
  content: " - Hi there";
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>Menu Option A</p>
  <p>Menu Option B</p>
</div>
<p>Doesn't get the :after effect</p>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: and still, you awarded a later answer :) you should definitely award this one as the answer as it is the most complete and it was the first one to answer the question :)

Answer (score 0):

[Combine :after with :hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233991/combine-after-with-hover)
this would work:

```
.parent p:hover:after {
    width: 2em;
}
```