# Hover with :after in CSS

Tags: css, hover

My HTML is like below

```
<li class="category">Hair</li>
```

My CSS code is like below

```
.category:hover:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "\f054" !important;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    right: 18px;
    top: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #ff0052;
}
```

When I hover on `Hair`, color is not changing to `#ff0052`.

Comment: remove the `:after`

Comment: Thanks @akaBase. But I need after also.

Comment: Also no need of `position: absolute;`.

Comment: remove    `right: 18px;` ..

Comment: you want to change the color of `:after` on hover, right?

Comment: @Simplicius, yes.

Comment: then `.category:hover :after`, just add a extra space.

Comment: @Simplicius, not working.

Comment: Yeah, true. Figured this aswell, might use `::after` instead of `:after`, see here: https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/JjXZjPm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine :after with :hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233991/combine-after-with-hover)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.category {
   position: relative;
   cursor: pointer;
}
.category:hover{
   color: red !important;
}

.category:hover::after {
   content: "++";
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: 900;
    top: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<li class="category">Hair</li>
```

Comment: Thanks @Abdulah Al Noor. But I need to change the color of `Hair` also. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Abdullah Al Noor. I would like to avoid this portion `.category:hover{
   color: red !important;
}`.

Comment: @abuabu i did not understand .. what do you want actually  ?

Comment: Actually I did like you before. But I would like to avoid `.category:hover{    color: red !important; }`. Is possible to get same functionality without that portion ? Thanks.

Comment: `::after` and `li.category` are two separate element ... i think it's not possible  ...