# CSS selector img:hover:after not being applied

Tags: css

I learned I can use [:hover:after](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13234028/667903) so I tried it myself, however it is not working:

```css
.img-shadow img:hover:after {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_left img-shadow">
    <figure class="wpb_wrapper vc_figure">
        <a href="#"><img width="100%" height="auto" src="http://dev.watmar.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Power_generation.jpg"></a>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does :before not work on img elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-elements)

Comment: What are you trying to do actually here? If your aim is to use pseudo-element then you can use it to add content before and after through, `::before` & `::after`. Single colon for pseudo class, double colon for pseudo element.  If in the above your aim is to add shadow you can add it directly, you need not use any pseudo-element for that. By using `inset` you can't see the shadow because it is inner side which is not visible, remove `inset` to see the shadow outside the image.

Comment: That answers my question @hashBender, add an answer if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do actually here? If your aim is to use pseudo-element then you can use it to add content before and after through, `::before` & `::after`. Single colon for pseudo class, double colon for pseudo element. If in the above your aim is to add shadow you can add it directly, you need not use any pseudo-element for that. By using `inset` you can't see the shadow because it is inner side which is not visible, remove `inset` to see the shadow outside the image.

Answer (score 0):

## Hello

Dear If you use :after pseudo selector you should use

```
content: "";
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

and its parent tag must use

```
position: relative;
```

but in your selected tag is not possible

```
position: relative;
```

in this case If you want to  use
`box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);`

You should must use padding inside the element, other wise you can not see the box-shadow.

For more Help you can visit this

#### [Demo](https://www.linkedin.com/in/masudrana2779/)

I can try to give you full support.

```css
.img-shadow img {
    transition: all 0.5s;
    padding: 20px;
}
.img-shadow img:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_left img-shadow">
    <figure class="wpb_wrapper vc_figure">
        <a href="#"><img width="100%" height="auto" src="http://dev.watmar.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Power_generation.jpg"></a>
    </figure>
</div>
```