# pseudo-class ::after doesn't work on my div

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I am trying to give the div element pseudo-class ::after when I hover the div. But it doesn't work.

It works when i follow the answer
Then I tried it to the img element but doesn't work

Any solution?

```css
.div {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 5.2rem;
  height: 5rem;
  border-radius: .75rem;
  margin-top: .75rem;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.div:hover::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
  z-index: 7;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}


<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
```

```
<img src="" alt="" class="div">
  <img src="" alt="" class="div">
  <img src="" alt="" class="div">
  <img src="" alt="" class="div">
```

Comment: As mentioned by @curveball you could try `.div:hover:after` or switch the order like `.div:after:hover`. In the past I had that same issue and by switching the order worked.

Comment: try the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233991/combine-after-with-hover)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector `.div:hover .div` match a `.div` inside a `.div`. What you want is the selector `.div:hover::after`:

```css
.div {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 5.2rem;
  height: 5rem;
  border-radius: .75rem;
  margin-top: .75rem;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.div:hover::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
  z-index: 7;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
```

Comment: It works, but when i change the div element with img element it doesn't work