# CSS3 list transition: position of bullets

Tags: html, list, css, hover, transition

I have created a menu with `li` elements. When `li:hover`, i would like to approximate list-style bullets to the text, and there would be a color changing too. 
(Both of them with `transition`, so `background-image` is unfit!)
I have already tried so many different ways, with relative positioning, and different margin settings, but none of them works properly. Is there any solution?
*(BTW, sorry for my poor english!)*

Comment: Have you tried a combination of `:hover` and `:before` pseudo-classes?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, but it was wrong. At least I can't find the right way.

Comment: Hello revotyx and welcome to stackoverflow. In order to get help please
Post some code and a fiddle. Tell us exactly  what doesn't work!

Comment: Wrong how? Please post an example to Pastebin.com or JSFiddle.net. Also, please have a look at this answer on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777210/how-to-write-hover-condition-for-abefore-and-aafter

Comment: So, there is my problem: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybtKQ/). The final result (after the transition) is CORRECT, but as you can see, the texts are moving too. But they should be static.

Answer (score 1):

**[Give this a whirl](http://jsfiddle.net/zLUn4/)**:

```
ul { 
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul li:before { 
    content: "\2022";
    opacity:0;
    padding:0 5px 0 10px;
    margin:0;
    transition:opacity 1s;
}
ul li:hover:before {
    opacity:1;
}
```

As suggested by @FK32 - we can use the `:before` pseudo-class to simulate a bullet point, by using the unicode character `\2022\`. We then initially set it's `opacity` to 0 and when the user hovers on the list item we change the opacity to 1, by apply a `transition:opacity 1s` so that we fade it in and out.

I removed any margin or padding that a user agent / custom stylesheet may have applied, and then adding padding to the `pseudo` so that you can more accurately space your list item's content from your bullet.