# CSS active selector using after pseudo element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have a problem to achieve on active icon selector on after pseudo selector. Below is the 
  code which am tried.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.btn{
width:25%;          
}
.name{
background: #fff;
color: #000;
text-align: center;
height: 35px;
line-height: 35px;
font-size: 18px;
border: 1px solid;  
} 
.name:after{
content: "";
position: absolute;
left: 210px;
top: 19px;
background-image: url('dark.png');
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
background-size: 100% auto; 
}
.name:after:active{
background-image: url('light.png');
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="btn name">Submit</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Light][image: Dark]

suggest me the approach to achieve the active selector using after pseudo selector.
  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

The pseudo-element needs to come last:

```
.name:active:after{
background-image: url('light.png');
}
```

If you're looking to change the pseudo-element style only when the pseudo-element is activated, that's not possible. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777210/how-to-write-hover-condition-for-abefore-and-aafter/5777334#5777334) for an explanation.

Comment: @Prashant: I'm not sure you understood either of my answers that you commented on. Please read them again.

Comment: If you don't need/want the parent element to handle pointer events, then you can put `pointer-events: none;` on the parent and `pointer-events: auto;` on the pseudo-element. This will cause the pseudo-element style to occur only when the pseudo-element is activated and nothing will happen if the parent is activated.