# How to change :before on hover state

Tags: html, css

I have some css I am working with, some links to be exact that have some :before on them for some aditional styling, I want the before to change background color when I hover on the .

Here's my poor attempt at it:

```
nav > li > a:hover a:before {
background-color: #fff

}
```

I just want to change the background color of the a:before when i hover over the a.

Thanks!!

Comment: You should find this very informative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777210/how-to-write-hover-condition-for-abefore-and-aafter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try joining them together like this:

```
nav > li > a:hover:before {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may also work for you.

```
nav > li > a:hover::before { background-color: #fff; }
```