# Hover State And JS Click Function On A CSS After Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a css after element that needs to function like a back to top of page button but for some reason the hover state and jQuery click function do not seem  to work. Not sure if its maybe a syntax error that I am missing?

HTML

```
<div id="divMain">
    ::after
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#divMain:after { content: 'Back  To Top'; position: relative; left: 93%; font-size: 16px; bottom: 30px; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; }
#divMain:after:hover { color: #b0f14f; }
```

JS/jQuery:

```
$('#divMain:after').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
    });
```

Comment: You can't access css pseudo elements through js. That's why they're called **pseudo** elements...

Comment: May be you can do it by applying `click` for `#divMain` instead of `#divMain:after`. Not sure about it.

Comment: You can do it check duplicate question....

Comment: Okay, I'll find another way of using the event then. Why wouldn't the hover state work though ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777210/how-to-write-hover-condition-for-abefore-and-aafter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17789110/3381024

the :after selector cannot be reached by jquery as it is not technically part of the DOM.

if you are using jquery anyway, append another class to it. however for the use of an absolutely positioned element, not sure why :after would be needed when you can just make a new element and style it up anyway

Comment: The problem is I am not able to edit the HTML and am creating the button purely for display purposes at the moment.

Comment: ok. if you hhave access to the javascript try `$("body").append()`

Comment: @Mikey

http://jsfiddle.net/L1suLj8a/