# Hover a pseudo element?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I know it is possible to do this

```
.parent:hover:before {
  color: 'blue';
}
```

But is it possible to listen for the hover on the pseudo element itself?

```
.parent:before:hover {
  color: 'blue';
}
```

**Edit**

Okay so it's impossible. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777210/how-to-write-hover-condition-for-abefore-and-aafter

Comment: That first chunk of code isn't CSS. What is that, less or sass?

Comment: even though the dupe question isn't exactly the same, you will find an answer in it.

Comment: Thank you web-tiki, found my answer after reading more carefully. Should I delete my question?

Comment: You don't have to - duplicates can serve as signposts for future searchers. That said, I thought I'd let you know that I've just updated my answer in the linked question. Hopefully it addresses your follow-up question.

Answer (score 1):

You have your selectors the wrong way round. try:

```
.parent:hover:before {
  color: 'blue'
}
```

---

Think of it like:

```
.AlwaysPut:hover:before{}
```

And then you can't go wrong! :D

---

**Pseudo Elements vs Pseudo Selectors**

> These are appropriately called pseudo "elements" (not selectors)
>   because they don't select any "real" element that exists on the page.
>   This goes for these two, as well as the previous sections
>   :first-letter and :first-line. Make sense? Like the first letter that
>   ::first-letter selects isn't an element all to itself, it's just a
>   part of an existing element, hence, pseudo element. ~[CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/)

Comment: Thanks but in the question I specify that I already know that's possible. I was wondering why the before cannot listen for a hover event

Comment: @plondon: That's because the 'pseudo' element isn't a *true* element of the DOM, and so you can't *'hover'* it.