# Using css class within another css class

Tags: html, css

I have following html

```
 <div class="popover"> click to popoverpopover</div>
```

When user mouse hover on div there should be a popover

My css is following

```
.popover:hover 
{
    content:"popover";

    .popover:before
    {
        content:'';
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 15px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border: 7px outset transparent;
        bottom: -14px;
        border-top: 7px solid #555;
    }
}
```

But I just found out that in CSS I can't use class within another class.

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying.

Comment: .popover:hover:before ?

Comment: i dont understand your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777210/how-to-write-hover-condition-for-abefore-and-aafter

Comment: @GCyrillus You are right. Now I have a pointer, thanks to you, how can I create popover body? thanks in advance

Comment: What is this 'popover' supposed to do? Does it have content in it?

Comment: @Paulie_D yes it supposed to be tool tip if u hover on things is supposed to appear

Comment: If you want **actual** content in the pop-over / tooltip then you can't use a pseudo-element. Use another div (inside the original div) instead and use that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a data-* attribute to hold rollover text.

```
<div class="wrap">
  <span data-rollover="Tool tip">Check</span>
</div>

span:hover {
  font-size: 0;
}

span:hover:before {
  font-size: 16px;
content: attr(data-rollover);
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cgm3c2us/

General idea taken from:
http://dabblet.com/gist/4286801