# Target for Hover to an already Hovered element

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I am trying to accomplish a hover effect in which when a div is hover a tick mark is appeared using the following code:

```
#asked-question-answers .question.ref-ans:hover::before{
    content: '\e8a7';
    speak: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 24px/1 'Material-Design-Icons';
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    transform: translate(0,0);
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 34px;
    color: #ccc;
}
```

[image: This is what the above code is doing]

Now I want to apply hover selected on that tick mark using following(failed try) code so that the gray tick becomes green:

```
#asked-question-answers .question.ref-ans::before:hover{
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Basically, you can't - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777210/how-to-write-hover-condition-for-abefore-and-aafter

Comment: If the tick mark becomes green on hover, then as a user I’d expect it to be some kind of control element (most likely checkbox functionality) – so why in that case is it only displayed via a CSS pseudo element, instead of being an `<input type=checkbox>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Paulie_D and CBroe, you are not able to define hover action on pseudo elements. What you can do instead is to create the tick mark as an `absolute` positioned element in your HTML markup with `opacity:0;`.

```
 #asked-question-answers .question.ref-ans #tickMark {
      position: absolute;
      top: ...;
      left: ...;
      opacity: 0;
      // other styling
}
```

On hover action on the parent element, you can change `opacity` like this:

```
#asked-question-answers .question.ref-ans:hover #tickMark {
      opacity: 1;
}
```

For the tick mark itself, you can define a hover action like this:

```
#tickMark:hover {
      color: green;
}
```

Remember that you can specify any acceptable type of selector instead of `#tickMark`.