# Hover and focus not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-animations

I currently trying to get a hover effect to work however I cannot seem to find the hover and focus states in inspect element so I think they not showing up anyone now where I am going wrong? Also worth noting I am running autoprefixer.

CSS

```
.nav-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  padding: 12px 10px 10px;
  flex-flow: column;
}
.nav-wrapper a {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.nav-wrapper a::before {
  color: green;
  content: attr(data-hover);
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 0.7s, opacity 0.7s;
}
.nav-wrapper a::before:hover, .nav-wrapper a::before:focus {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
  <nav class="nav-wrapper">
    <a class="nav-child" data-hover="About Me" href="#">About Me</a>
    <a class="nav-child" data-hover="Work" href="#">Work</a>
    <a class="nav-child" data-hover="Process" href="#">Process</a  >
    <a class="nav-child" data-hover="Contact Me" href="#">Contact Me</a>
  </nav>
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777210/how-to-write-hover-condition-for-abefore-and-aafter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
.nav-wrapper a::before:hover, .nav-wrapper a::before:focus
```

to

```
.nav-wrapper a:hover::before, .nav-wrapper a:focus::before
```

The `:hover` and `:focus` selectors are pseudo-classes, and therefore should take precedence over pseudo-elements such as `::before` and `::after`.

Answer (score 0):

::before and :focus/:hover have to be switched.

Oh, I see someone else was before me xD