# How to put a hover effect to an after content is css?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I want to show a div named dot-menu when hover the after content of h1. I have tried the following code but did't work.

```css
h1{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #3d3d3d;
    margin-top:50px
}
 h1:after{
    content: "\22EE";
    float: right;
    font-size: 35px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.dot-menu{
    float: right;
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: "Montserrat Light", "Open Sans";
    position: relative;
    top:-10px;
    opacity:0;
}
h1:after:hover .dot-menu{
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Henry Little</h1><h3 class="dot-menu">about</h3>
```

Comment: check this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered

Comment: Check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777210/how-to-write-hover-condition-for-abefore-and-aafter

Comment: Seems you have wrong idea about hover. You can change style of the child element on hover to the parent.

Comment: you ll have to write javascript/jQuery to change the style of parent while hover on child element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Your selector `h1:after:hover .dot-menu` is wrong.

This selector will look for `.dot-menu` element that is descendant of `h1` but this is not the case. And 2nd you can't select another element on hover of a pseudo element.

You will need to change your code a bit. Consider the following `HTML`:

```
<h1>Henry Little
  <span class="icon">&vellip;</span>
  <span class="dot-menu">about</span>
</h1>
```

Make menu opener and menu both child elements of same parent. Then you can show menu on hover of icon with Sibling (`+` ) selector.

```
h1 .icon:hover + .dot-menu{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```css
h1{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #3d3d3d;
  margin-top:50px;
  position: relative;
}

h1:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}
h1 .icon {
  float: right;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dot-menu {
  float: right;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Montserrat Light", "Open Sans";
  position: relative;
  top:30px;
  opacity:0;
  right: 0;
}
h1 .icon:hover + .dot-menu{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Henry Little
  <span class="icon">&vellip;</span>
  <div class="dot-menu">about</div>
</h1>
```

Comment: This seems like the desired effect, but having a `<div>` inside `<h1>` is invalid markup. Please correct accordingly.

Comment: @JIBINBJ you are welcome. Please mark any answer as accepted that solved your problem. This might help others looking for solution of similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

See this just after making the `.dot-menu` a child of `h1` it is working.

```css
h1{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #3d3d3d;
    margin-top:50px
}
 h1:after{
    content: "\22EE";
    float: right;
    font-size: 35px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.dot-menu{
    float: right;
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: "Montserrat Light", "Open Sans";
    position: relative;
    top:-10px;
    opacity:0;
}
h1:hover .dot-menu{
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Henry Little<span class="dot-menu">about</span></h1>
```

Comment: Looks good.But i want to show the div only hover the after content.Not the h1

Comment: I know I just gave you this to tell how exactly hover works with the child. :)