# How can i use hover effect on after element with css?

Tags: css

This is my code, I want to show hover effect on after element.

```
 #car:after:hover{background:red:}
```

but this is not working.

Comment: The element itself receives the event, not its pseudo element (also, syntax errors): `#car:hover::after { background: red; }`

Comment: `#car:hover::after{background:red}`

Comment: Check this out I guess it would solve your problems.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777210/how-to-write-hover-condition-for-abefore-and-aafter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out this demo below. I think you are missing `content` property.

the `Red` `div` is created using `:after` and changes its color on hover.

the `selector:after:hover` won't work.

```css
.car {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.car:hover {
  background: skyblue;
}

.car:after {
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: green;
}

.car:hover:after {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="car"></div>
```