# How can you make a droppable hexagon hover when dragged over?

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-class, jquery-ui-droppable

This is an easy one, but I am stuck and hope you can help me out here [(DEMO)](https://jsfiddle.net/FrauKaaa/11e30qb3/10/):

Consider two hexagons (`.drag-hex` and `.drop-hex`), build out of a rectangle with appended `:before` and `:after` triangles:

```
.drop-hex {
position: relative;
width: 250px;
height: 144.34px;
background-color: white;
margin: 72.17px 0;
float: left;
cursor: pointer;
margin-left: 5.5px;
margin-bottom: 5.5px;
}

.drop-hex:before,
.drop-hex:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
width: 0;
border-left: 125px solid transparent;
border-right: 125px solid transparent;
}

.drop-hex:before {
bottom: 100%;
border-bottom: 72.17px solid white;
}

.drop-hex:after {
top: 100%;
width: 0;
border-top: 72.17px solid white;
}

.drag-hex {
position: relative;


width: 250px;
  height: 144.34px;
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 72.17px 0;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 5.5px;
  margin-bottom: 5.5px;
}

.drag-hex:before,
.drag-hex:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 125px solid transparent;
  border-right: 125px solid transparent;
}

.drag-hex:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 72.17px solid tomato;
}

.drag-hex:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 72.17px solid tomato;
}
```

[image: the hexagons]

Now, `drop-hex` (white) should hover with a black border, when `drag-hex` (red) is touching `drop-hex`.

I tried the following in order to get this effect (drag and drop is fine):

```
  $(function() {
  $(".drag-hex").draggable({
    snap: ".drop-hex",
    snapMode: "inner",
    snapTolerance: 10
  });

  $(".drop-hex").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover"
  });
});
```

and tried (cluelessly) to customise the hover event:

```
#drop .ui-state-hover:before:after {
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Two questions:

1. How can I make the *whole* hexagon hover (not only the inner `.drop-hex` rectangle?) I found similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777210/how-to-write-hover-condition-for-abefore-and-aafter) about hover and pseudo classes, but couldn't relate it to my case.
2. Can you explain the concept of `ui-droppable-hover` property and [classes](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-classes) to me? The deprecated `hoverClass` seemed so much easier.