# Problems with hover and before CSS3

Tags: css, mobile-website, vs-web-site-project

Is it possible to make a `:hover` on the `:before` element so that something shows over it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777210/how-to-write-hover-condition-for-abefore-and-aafter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write :hover condition for a:before and a:after?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777210/how-to-write-hover-condition-for-abefore-and-aafter)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done like..

```
.selector:hover:before {/* css rule goes here */}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to add a `:hover` style (or `:active`, or `:focus`) to any elements like `:before` or `:after`. They would have to be applied to an actual HTML element, not a pseudo-element.

From your screenshot, it appears you're trying to create a hover menu. Depending on your styles, you may be able to apply the `:hover` styles to the ul itself. However, you'll only be able to control `ul` styles with CSS - you cannot control `li` styles based on the hover state of their parent without JS.

If JS is an option, use it - it should be pretty simple in this case, and would make the code a lot easier. If css-only is a requirement, you might be able to get around this by setting the `<ul>` to a specific height (large enough to show the `hover` item but nothing else), and give `ul:hover` a larger height, or `height: auto;`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Its called offcanvas

Refer https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_off-canvas.asp

AND https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

Let me know if you require any further help