# Vuejs apply loop in css to put hover

Tags: css, vuejs2

In VueJS, I have elements that have hover property in my object.

So, I want to put a foreach in style, but it is not possible.

I want to do that kind of thing :

```
<style>
  @foreach (element in elements) {    
    if (element.has_backgroundhover) {
        '#'+element.id:hover {
           background : element.background_hover;
        }
    }    
 }
</style>
```

Notice that each element has a background color different (it is stored in his oibject property)

Thank you

Comment: You can't do that with CSS, since the element's background color is set at runtime while the CSS is compiled at build time. What you want is to bind `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, and set the background color using `Element.style` API instead. [Can you share a minimal, concrete and verifiable example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this?
The HTML:

```
    <div id="app">
      <div 
        v-for="element of elements"
        @mouseenter="element.hover=true"
        @mouseleave="element.hover=false"
        :style="{
          background: element.hover? element.background_hover : element.background
        }"
      >{{element.name}}</div>
    </div>
```

And the JS:

```
    new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: {
        elements:[
          {
            name:"element1", 
            background:"#f8f", 
            background_hover:"#a4a",
            hover:false
          },
          {
            name:"element2", 
            background:"#ff8", 
            background_hover:"#aa4",
            hover:false
          },
        ]
      },
    })
```

This is not using the CSS, rather using events as suggested by @DigitalDrifter.  I think the point is that reactive css is not a good idea, and not supported in vue.  Instead you need to have the HTML element properties dependent on your vue data object.  A fiddle for this is: https://jsfiddle.net/edzaokum/

Comment: thank you, just a question, why using "mouseenter" not "mouseover" ?

Comment: see the mdn documentation for mouseover: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover.  Basically mouseenter happens once, mouseover can happen many times while the cursor is moving over the target.  The property only needs be changed once.

Comment: thanx a lot my friend :)

Comment: what about setting color to :before
changing color on hover to the :before (color are also in properties of the element)

Comment: :before is a css selector, not css styling.  This can't be changed by vue in this way.  IF you have a restricted number of colours you want to apply THEN you could do all of this with classes.  i.e. have a `.bluehover:hover:before {background:blue} .redhover ...` (as well as other colours) and then get vue to add a css style depending on the colour `:class="element.background_hover+'hover'"` and here `background_hover` would be one of your list of colours.  If you want to appy ANY colour then this does not work and you need to use the solution above.

Comment: This is another question : each element has :before  on it's <div>  and each element has a different color for that :before on hover..... 

for exemple : 
`elemnt 1 : background_color_before : red,  background_color_hover_before : blue`
....
what can i do for setting different background color to :before with mouseover ?

Comment: and BTW ensure in the css you put `:hover` before `::before` - pseudo-elements must come after a pseudo-class (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777210/how-to-write-hover-condition-for-abefore-and-aafter)

Comment: This demonstrates the use of classes with hover and before. (a re-creation of a previous comment, as something seemed to go wrong with saving it before): https://jsfiddle.net/te1gLvo8/

Comment: thank you, but I'm talking about changing :bufore background color (setting color from object property to :before on hover)

Comment: You can only change pseudo-elements by adding or removing classes from the related HTML element.  If that does not do what you want, then you need to add real HTML instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `@mouseenter` and `@mouseleave` event listeners would allow for css classes to be applied to each element.

For example, toggle a `.hovered` class that has the background color defined.

Comment: but my color are in a variable, each element has it own background in variable