# Adding :hover to a content property

Tags: html, css, hover, pseudo-element

I want to change the style of the content created by CSS using content: "" property when the user hovers over it.

```
.breadcrumb li{
  display: inline;
}
.breadcrumb li.location+li.location::before {
  content: ">";
  color: green;
  padding-right: 2.5px;
}
li.attribute a:hover {
  color:blue;
}
li.attribute::after{
  content: "x";
  color: gray;
  vertical-align: super;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

SO I want the x to turn red when it's hovered over. I tried using :

```
li.attribute:hover::after{
  color: red;
}
```

But it's making it red when I hover over the word "Organic" itself as well as the content"x".

HTML:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li  class="location">
    <a href="#">Shop</a>
  </li>
  <li  class="location">
    <a href="#">Groceries</a>
  </li>
  <li  class="location">
    <a href="#">Blueberries</a>
  </li>
  <li class="attribute">
    <a href="#">Organic</a>
  </li>
```

```css
.breadcrumb li{
  display: inline;
}
.breadcrumb li.location+li.location::before {
  content: ">";
  color: green;
  padding-right: 2.5px;
}
li.attribute a:hover {
  color:blue;
}
li.attribute::after{
  content: "x";
  color: gray;
  vertical-align: super;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
}
li.attribute:hover::after{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li  class="location">
    <a href="#">Shop</a>
  </li>
  <li  class="location">
    <a href="#">Groceries</a>
  </li>
  <li  class="location">
    <a href="#">Blueberries</a>
  </li>
  <li class="attribute">
    <a href="#">Organic</a>
  </li>
```

Comment: i think it is impossible according to this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/5777334/9140740

Comment: Do you want to use `::after` only to insert the "x"? Or you can use some other method?

Comment: I am currently learning to create breadcrumb navigation and so I would rather use `::after`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind editing the html, then you can insert a `sup` tag instead of `::after` pseudo element and apply the css accordingly -

```css
.breadcrumb li{
  display: inline;
}
.breadcrumb li.location+li.location::before {
  content: ">";
  color: green;
  padding-right: 2.5px;
}
li.attribute a:hover {
  color:blue;
}
li.attribute sup{
  color: gray;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
}
li.attribute sup:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li  class="location">
    <a href="#">Shop</a>
  </li>
  <li  class="location">
    <a href="#">Groceries</a>
  </li>
  <li  class="location">
    <a href="#">Blueberries</a>
  </li>
  <li class="attribute">
    <a href="#">Organic</a>
    <sup>x</sup>
  </li>
```

Comment: Thank you @praneet for the alternative, however, I am currently learning to create breadcrumb navigation and so I would rather use `::after` in CSS

Comment: I am not saying that you replace everything. Keep your code and logic, but you can apply these changes just to the "x" so that you can achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Actually, the whole purpose of the question is to know if I can style the `:hover` of a `content: ""`. not to add the x itself.

Comment: Adding a `:hover` state to a `::before` or `::after` pseudo elements is not possible.